# CakePHP: upgrade from 3.6.x to 4.0 "Missing Template Exception"

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, upgrade, cakephp-4.x

I followed the [upgrade guide](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/4-0-upgrade-guide.html) (after I upgraded from `3.6` to `3.8`) but I get this error:

> Error: [Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException] Template file "Error\error500.ctp" is missing
>
> ....
>
> *If you want to customize this error message, create src\Template\Error\fatal_error.ctp*

After the upgrade procedure my templates moved to `app_name\templates` directory and renamed to `*.php` instead of `*.ctp` . I updated the `app.php` and `app.default.php` with the new paths:

```
'App' => [
        'namespace' => 'App',
        'encoding' => env('APP_ENCODING', 'UTF-8'),
        'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_US'),
        'defaultTimezone' => env('APP_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'),
        'base' => false,
        'dir' => 'src',
        'webroot' => 'webroot',
        'wwwRoot' => WWW_ROOT,
        //'baseUrl' => env('SCRIPT_NAME'),
        'fullBaseUrl' => false,
        'imageBaseUrl' => 'img/',
        'cssBaseUrl' => 'css/',
        'jsBaseUrl' => 'js/',
        'paths' => [
            'plugins' => [ROOT . DS . 'plugins' . DS],
            'templates' => [ROOT . DS . 'templates' . DS],
            'locales' => [ROOT . DS  . 'Locale' . DS],
        ],
    ],
```

But still the application is looking for the template files with `.ctp` extension and under `src\Template\...`

What am I missing?

Comment: try ```bin/cake cache clear_all```

Comment: @Salines didn't help.... again the same error

Comment: composer update?

Comment: Ive done it before all operations

Comment: hm, look at composer , what is cakephp version

Comment: @Salines 3.8.0 :(

Answer (score 1):

From my experience:

**Upgrade CakePHP 3.x to 4.x**

- composer update
- run phpstan from --level 0 to 2 and fix your code or test in scrutinizer
- read 4.0 Migration Guide : https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/4-0-migration-guide.html
- read 4.0 Upgrade Guide : https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/4-0-upgrade-guide.html
  Steps:
- Install the upgrade tool
- Rename locale files
- Rename template files
- Once you've renamed your template and locale files, make sure you update App.paths.locales and App.paths.templates paths to be correct.
- From your app composer file remove all cakephp/*  (cakephp3) packages, also phpstan, code  standards, phpunit,.. run `composer update`
- Applying Rector Refactorings
- `composer require --update-with-dependencies "phpunit/phpunit:^8.0"`
- `composer require --update-with-dependencies "cakephp/cakephp:4.0.*"`
- Install fresh cakephp4 inside your app folder. Example: `mkdir cakephp4  && cd cakeph4`; and run `composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app:4.*  .`;
- compare your old  cakephp files with files from cakephp4 folder, update all and copy missing files
- delete cakephp4 and upgrade folders
- don't forget at top of you php files to add `<?php declare(strict_types=1);`
- `composer cs-check` then `composer cs-fix`

Comment: Hi there, thanks for sharing your way to go. I just followed your way and saw, that the order of the steps "remove all cakephp3-packages" and "apply rector refactorings" must be switched. After removing cakephp-packes, rector can't apply changes due to missing classes. Despite of that, very nice. Can you shortly give an explanation or command, how to do step 2?

Comment: @MikeRoss step 2: Rename locale files ?? Or?

Comment: I meant step "run phpstan from --level 0 to 2 and fix your code or test in scrutinizer" could include a short explanation of how to run this command (e.g. for me, I didn't use phpstan before). Some that might read your instructions (that worked pretty good, btw) may be thankful.

Comment: @MikeRoss ```composer require --dev phpstan/phpstan``` then in console run ```./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse src plugins --level 0``` this command output some basic errors, with level 1 you have deeper outputs, etc. Try to find  and fix error and Deprecations warnings. For example $this->request->..  emit Deprecated warning ..

Comment: "After removing cakephp-packes, rector can't apply changes due to missing classes."  remove from composer file,  not from vendor folder

Comment: Thanks for the command. Will try this with my second project. Regarding your last comment ("remove from composer file, not from vendor folder"): I removed from composer.json and then - just like you told in this step, ran composer update. Maybe, I deleted too many packages ;)