# Cakephp upgrading from 3.6.16 to 4.2 rector command not working bin/cake upgrade rector --rules phpunit80 C:\Apache24\htdocs\Techno\tests

Tags: php, cakephp, migration, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-4.x

I am upgrading the existing `Cakephp-3.6.16` to `Cakephp-4.2`and when firing the below **step-4** `Rector` command it return the PHP Fatal error.

I followed the below steps for the upgrade

1 Install the upgrade tool

```
git clone git://github.com/cakephp/upgrade
cd upgrade
git checkout master
composer install --no-dev
```

2. Rename locale files [This command run successfully]

> C:\Apache24\htdocs\latest\Techno\upgrade\bin>cake upgrade file_rename
> locales C:/Apache24/htdocs/latest/Techno

3. This command run successfully and upgrade .crt file to .php in “src/templates” folder and the folder is now moved from “Techno/src/templates” to root folder “Techno/templates”.

> C:\Apache24\htdocs\latest\Techno\upgrade> cake upgrade file_rename
> templates C:/Apache24/htdocs/latest/Techno

4. **This two Rector Refactorings commands are not working and throwing error**

> C:\Apache24\htdocs\latest\Techno\upgrade\bin> **cake upgrade rector
> --rules phpunit80 C:/Apache24/htdocs/latest/Techno/tests**
>
> C:\Apache24\htdocs\latest\Techno\upgrade\bin> **cake upgrade rector
> --rules cakephp40 C:/Apache24/htdocs/latest/Techno/src**

---

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Rector\Core\Console\Style\SymfonyStyleFactory' not found in C:\Apache24\htdocs\Techno\upgrade\vendor\rector\rector\bin\rector.php:38
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\Techno\upgrade\vendor\rector\rector\bin\rector(4): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\Techno\upgrade\vendor\rector\rector\bin\rector.php on line 38
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Rector\Core\Console\Style\SymfonyStyleFactory' not found in C:\Apache24\htdocs\Techno\upgrade\vendor\rector\rector\bin\rector.php:38
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\Techno\upgrade\vendor\rector\rector\bin\rector(4): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\Techno\upgrade\vendor\rector\rector\bin\rector.php on line 38
```

Is there any steps I missed for upgradaion ?

Comment: try first to upgrade to cake 4.0, then to a newer version.

Comment: From my experience rector is pretty volatile, and can break from one minute to the other, and on Windows it seems to have issues in general. So, maybe give a linux based VM/container a try, and try a different rector version by pinning it in the upgrade app's `composer.json`.

Comment: @Salines Yes, I tried to upgrade CakePHP from 3.3.16 to 4.0 version and got this errors.

Comment: read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60260874/1127933

Comment: @ndm Which version of `rector` you suggest for windows?  I have installed rector/rector                    - 0.9.16

Comment: None, it never worked for me on Windows, hence I'm suggesting a VM/container.