# Cake php Migration and Upgrade to version 4

Tags: cakephp, migration, upgrade, cakephp-4.x, cakephp3

I am upgrading and migration cake php from version 3.8 to 4 everything goes fine following the steps(https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/4-0-upgrade-guide.html) but as per the migration and upgrade documentation cake php version 4 supports ".php" and when I updated the versions i am getting error for missing ".ctp" file.

"Confirm you have created the file": "Dashboard/index.ctp"

Below Image shows the error.[image]

Comment: clear cache: bin/cake cache clear_all

Comment: i have tried the above command, but no luck with this. I also tried to change the extension in 

/code/vendor/wyrihaximus/twig-view/src/View/TwigView.php
protected $extensions = [
        self::EXT,
        '.tpl',
        '.ctp',
        '.php'
    ];

code/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/View/BakeView.php
['.php','.ctp', '.twig', DS],

but still i am getting error

Comment: I don't think you upgraded CakePHP, try: `bin/cake version` and tell us which version is currently.

Comment: also read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60260091/cakephp-upgrade-from-3-6-x-to-4-0-missing-template-exception/60260874#60260874